# Which isometries allow us to tile aperiodically?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, isometry, tiling

A recent Quanta article [1] discusses a new result of Greenfeld & Tao [2]:

> There is some dimension $d$ with a $d$-dimensional tile which aperiodically fills $\mathbb{R}^d$ but cannot do so periodically, allowing translations, rotations, and reflections.

Bhattacharya [3] had earlier proved that this is not possible (for $d=2$) with translations alone:

> Any tile which aperiodically fills $\mathbb{R}^2$ can also fill it periodically, allowing only translations.

Is anything known about the remaining cases? In particular, I am curious about allowing translations and rotations but not reflections, but any other collections of allowed isometries would be of interest.

Edit: Dan Rust brings up disconnected tiles in the comments. I'm happy to allow them, but it might be interesting to consider both cases.

[1] Jordana Cepelewicz, [‘Nasty’ Geometry Breaks Decades-Old Tiling Conjecture](https://www.quantamagazine.org/nasty-geometry-breaks-decades-old-tiling-conjecture-20221215/), *Quanta Magazine* (Dec 2022)

[2] Rachel Greenfeld and Terence Tao, [A counterexample to the periodic tiling conjecture](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.15847), arXiv preprint (2022). arXiv:2211.15847 [math.CO]

[3] Siddhartha Bhattacharya, [Periodicity and decidability of tilings of $\mathbb{Z}^2$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.05738), *American Journal of Mathematics*, Volume 142, Number 1 (Feb 2020), pp. 255-266. arXiv:1602.05738 [math.CO]

Comment: Doesn't the [Socolar-Taylor tile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socolar%E2%80%93Taylor_tile) already do this in dimension 3 (or 2 if you allow it to be disconnected)?

Comment: @DanRust It does do it in dimension 2 (I didn't add disconnection as a parameter, but that might be a reasonable thing to do). In dimension 3 it does tile aperiodically but it also tiles periodically.